# Accept simple format null for XmlElement parameter

Tags: xml, wcf, null, asmx

I'm building a WCF service (.Net 3.5, IIS Hosted) to replace an old ASMX style service. It has to be **very** compatible with the old style interface, to avoid effort by the vendors who write the software that calls it. (Some of them build a simple XML data structure, bang it inside a pre-prepared SOAP "template" and throw it at my service. I need to accept their *existing* XML structure).

For compatibility with the way these clients call the service I've had to define the operation as:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:namespacex")]
public interface IServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    System.Xml.XmlElement OperationA(int parmB, System.Xml.XmlElement parmC);
}
```

i.e. the parameters are in the OperationContract, not pulled out into seperate DataMember elements in a DataContract. The XmlElement used here, replaces an XmlNode parameter used in the old ASMX service.

It's implemented as:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "urn:namespacey")]
public class TheService : IServices
{
    public System.Xml.XmlElement OperationA(int parmB, System.Xml.XmlElement parmC)
    {
        ... code to handle call
    }
}
```

It works fine... when there is data to send.

The issue I'm having is when the parmC input is null, which is allowed. Sometimes it has data, sometimes it doesn't. One caller is sending this in the SOAP message for a null parmC:

```
<parmC/>
```

i.e. a simple empty XML element.

This is raising the following error from WCF:

> Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'EndElement'  with name
>   'parmC', namespace 'urn:namespacex'.

So it seems it isn't liking the simple null element input. (The service works fine if there is actually some data in there.)

Tracing my own test caller (which works with and without information in the parmC parameter), I can see that for null my (.Net WCF) tester is sending:

```
<parmC xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:nil="true"/>
```

Attempt 1:

Looking for help, I've noted the "[XmlSerializerFormat]" attribute that is supposed to make the service act more like old style ASMX, by not using the newer data contract serialiser. My test caller (.Net, WCF) then sends nothing at all for the null. But this client still gets an error, though it is a different message now, in reference to that element:

> No corresponding start element is open.

Attempt 2:

Then I remembered the oldest version of the original ASMX service used a string to accept that data. (It loaded that string into an XML object server-side, within the handler for the operation). So I changed the contract and operation to define parmC as string, instead of XmlElement.

Suddenly the service is accepting various forms of empty parmC. (Using a quick test app that posts raw SOAP to my service, so I can simulate what these vendors do).

But - if there is actually data in there, it fails, with:

> Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'OperatonA'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error
>   in XML document (99, 99). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: End element
>   'parmC' from namespace 'urn:namespacex' expected. Found element 'a'
>   from namespace ''

(when XML data is sent in parmC, it looks like this in the SOAP:

```
<parmC>
  <a xmlns="">bbb</a>
</parmC>
```

)

Clearly, it's not expecting in this case to find XML inside the string (the 'a' element); but this used to work in ASMX so was "worth a shot".

---

So I can't find a combination of settings that allows both XML data to be sent to the service, while also allowing that clients style of empty or null data.

Do I have to implement a custom deserialiser? Is there a setting somewhere that'll help?

(So far I've managed to keep everything WCF related purely in configuration, I'd like to keep it that way if I can.)

In summary, I need a WCF service that will cope with either of these coming over the wire:

```
<s:Body>
  <OperationA xmlns="urn:namespacex">
    <parmB>1</parmB>
    <parmC> { this works fine }
     <a xmlns="">
      <b>bbb</b>
     </a>
    </parmC>
  </OperationA>
</s:Body>

<s:Body>
  <OperationA xmlns="urn:namespacex">
    <parmB>1</parmB>
    <parmC/> { I need this to be accepted }
  </OperationA>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your answers with "WCF" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

The XML for the two options you present is **not** equivalent. There is a very subtle difference between the two that is probably the cause of your problem. The option with `<a xmlns="">` is setting the element **a** and its child elements to have no default *XML namespace*. The other option (the "null" parameter option) doesn't contain the "re-definition" of the default XML namespace from "urn:namespacex" to "" so when the deserialization process is parsing parmC for element `<a xmlns="">` it can't find it. If you read the exception message carefully, it is actually telling you this.

As to how to support the two scenarios, try getting your client to send this instead of what they're sending now:

```
<parmC>
 <a xmlns="">
  <b />
 </a>
</parmC>
```

or possibly:

```
<parmC>
 <a xmlns="" />
</parmC>
```

Comment: Thanks. The <a> element isn't defined in the contract, it's just an example of what XML data sent to parameter parmC looks like on the wire. This - works - when parmC is defined as XmlElement. The null namespace on <a>, I believe, essentially lets the desrialiser note that it isn't part of the defined message format, and that's why it doesn't complain about <a> being unexpected. The issue is when parmC is null. The two formats work in the old ASMX web service, so I'm just looking for a way for the WCF service to accept the same format of data.

Comment: The biggest issue I face, is I - can't - get the client to change what they are sending. If I could, then I'd just get them to send the same `<parmC xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:nil="true"/>` that my test caller sends for null.

Comment: Sounds like you need to hook up custom deserializer to tweak the incoming soap to match what WCF is looking for. This (long) [blog post on serializers](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) will get you started. The other option is use MessageContract instead of DataContract but that way is painful too. You'll need to choose your poison :(

Comment: Yeah, it was certainly looking like that. Thanks for the link.